# yii2 calculate selected row in grid-view (checkbox-column) using jquery and submit the data

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

I have a gridview like code below

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'table-penerimaan-produksi',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'checkboxOptions' =>
                function($model) {
                    return ['value' => $model->id, 'class' => 'checkbox-row'];
                }
        ],
        'ref.id',
        'ref.send_date',
        'received_date',
        'ref.vehicle_id',
        ['attribute' => 'netto', 'label' => 'Netto Terima', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]],
        ['attribute' => 'ref.netto', 'label' => 'Netto Kirim', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]],
        ['attribute' => 'susut', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]]
    ],
]); ?>
```

what i want is to calculate netto from selected row by using jquery.
i have jquery like this:

```
$('.select-on-check-all, .checkbox-row').click(function(){
    calculateNetto();
})

function calculateNetto()
{
    var keys = $('#table-penerimaan-produksi').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');        
}
```

How to get the value from keys and post to controller to save the ids selected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap gridview with activeForm.

Comment: already do that.

Comment: this is [my code](https://gist.github.com/wilsonxyz/b8b58c50f132bb9642e4eea509c7746a)

Comment: Submit the form and check `Yii::$app->request->post()`.

Comment: how about iteration to calculate selected row netto ?

Comment: what do you want to calculate?

Comment: total netto and ref.netto.

Comment: want to display or post to controller?

Comment: calculate i already got the answers. remain post to controller. tomorrow to be continue. thanks for reply @InsaneSkull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer for calculating netto column which are selected using jquery

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'checkboxOptions' =>
        function($model) {
            return ['value' => $model->id, 'class' => 'checkbox-row', 'id' => 'checkbox'];
        }
],
```

Adding id to CheckboxColumn and then using the following code to calculate netto

```
$('.select-on-check-all, .checkbox-row').click(function(){
    calculateNetto();
})

function calculateNetto()
{            
    var total_netto_send = 0; var total_netto_receive = 0;
    var netto_send = 0; var netto_receive = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < $('#checkbox.checkbox-row').length; i++)
    {           
        if($('#checkbox.checkbox-row')[i].checked == true) {
            netto_send = document.getElementById('table-penerimaan-produksi').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i+1].getElementsByTagName('td')[6].innerHTML;
            netto_receive = document.getElementById('table-penerimaan-produksi').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i+1].getElementsByTagName('td')[5].innerHTML;
            netto_send = netto_send == "" ? 0 : Number(netto_send.split(",").join(""));
            netto_receive = netto_receive == "" ? 0 : Number(netto_receive.split(",").join(""));
            total_netto_send += netto_send;
            total_netto_receive += netto_receive;
        }           
    }    
    $('#realisasiproduksi-total_netto_send').val(total_netto_send);
    $('#realisasiproduksi-total_netto_receive').val(total_netto_receive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set selected rows count in a hidden field, and get it into your controller using Yii::$app->request->post() method. See following steps to get the desired result:

1) Add public variable in model:

```
// Model
public class TestModel extends Model {
    public $rows_count;
}
```

2) Add form and input field in view

```
// View
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'table-penerimaan-produksi',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'checkboxOptions' =>
                function($model) {
                    return ['value' => $model->id, 'class' => 'checkbox-row'];
                }
        ],
        'ref.id',
        'ref.send_date',
        'received_date',
        'ref.vehicle_id',
        ['attribute' => 'netto', 'label' => 'Netto Terima', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]],
        ['attribute' => 'ref.netto', 'label' => 'Netto Kirim', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]],
        ['attribute' => 'susut', 'format' => ['decimal', 2]]
    ],
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'rows_count')->hiddenInput(['id' => 'rows_count']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

3) Set total selected rows count in hidden field

```
// Javascript Code
function calculateNetto() {
    var keys = $('#table-penerimaan-produksi').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $('#rows_count').val(keys);
}
```

4) Get total rows count in controller

```
// Controller
public function actionTestController() {
    $rows_count = Yii::$app->request->post('rows_count');
}
```

Let me know if any help needed.

**Edit**
If you don't select all rows, then .yiiGridView('getSelectedRows') would return empty array, otherwise it would return array of selected row values. One more thing I would like to change in javascript code that instead of click event, use change event as follows, because it would give accurate result:

```
$('.select-on-check-all, .checkbox-row').click(function(){  // Here use change event instead of click event
    calculateNetto();
})
```

Comment: what if not all rows selected?

Comment: If you don't select all rows, then .yiiGridView('getSelectedRows') would return empty array, otherwise it would return array of selected row values. One more thing I would like to change in javascript code that instead of click event, use change event as follows, because it would give accurate result, see updated answer

Comment: so, how can we know rows selected? because i want to sum the netto which selected.